# Jenkins Blue Ocean - How to skip the first build on Branch indexing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

There is `Build Strategies` tab according to [skipping-first-build-first-branch-indexing](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/skipping-first-build-first-branch-indexing) to **Skip initial build on first branch indexing**

This feature is helpful such as re-create Blue Ocean pipeline after deleted the old one or moved to a new jenkins without deploying.

So is there a similar solution for Blue Ocean(project bases on MultiBranch Pipeline)?

(My Pipeline is created using Git)

[image]

Comment: Blue Ocean is just an output plugin. You should configure your Multi-Branch Pipeline  and in the Branch Sources, choose "Git" or "GitHub" as source. Both have "Add Build Strategy" button where one of the options is "Skip initial build".

Comment: @MaratC Thanks for the tips. I solved my problem by installing the I-forgot-to-install plugin - `Basic Branch Build Strategies Plugin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to install the specific plugin - `Basic Branch Build Strategies Plugin`.

After installed the plugin should work for `Multibranch Pipeline` projects

[image]

[image]